# Add additional information to joined rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

How can I add additional information to joined rows?

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
    ON column1 = col1_table2 //The row which matches with this join should have additional information e.g. "'joined' AS info
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Huh? Do you mean that the row should contain that information or the column name should be appended with joined? Also, what RDBMS?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You want to have the string 'Joined' somewhere to identify the data is from the joined table, or that a joined record was found?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    t1.column1, 
    t1.column2, 
    CASE WHEN t2.col1_table2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'joined' END AS info
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.col1_table2
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2,  
       CASE WHEN col1_table2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'joined' END AS additional_field 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON column1 = col1_table2
```